# Custom (different than Google Map) Map in Android

Tags: android, maps, custom-controls

I want to use some other Map instead of using Google Map.

So please suggest how I can initiate such thing in Android.

Provide some link or code snippet.

Regards,

Parmanand

Comment: take a look at this one : http://developer.here.com/native-apis;jsessionid=09CF2FD6D5C6B24E0532939918C0E6F4

Comment: Yes its good but I want to use my own map (some predefined url)....how can I show whole map without using Google Map.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by using the Google Maps API v2 and subclassing UrlTileProvider. I discuss this approach in my online guide here: http://guides.cocoahero.com/google-maps-android-custom-tile-providers.html